# Over ride saveChanges when using EFContextProvider in Breeze

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I am using breeze with EF. I want to implement auditing but I cant use DbContext's save changes as I am using Breeze's EFContextprovider . Anyone has a clue how to go about it ? Thanks in advance.

I should mention that I have tried to extend the BeforeSaveEntity method as described here http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider#SaveInterception but the code never seems to get called.

Thanks for replying . Heres some pseudo code. The auditing method never gets hit

```
BaseDBCntext:DBContext{}//DbContext

[BreezeController]
MyController:ApiController //Controller
{
private readonly MyRepository _context = new MyRepository(); 

 [HttpGet]
 public string MetaData()
 {
            return _context.Metadata();
  }

[HttpGet]
public void saveEntry(){

    return _context.saveEntry();

}   


}

MyRepository:EFContextProvider<BaseDBContext>,IDisposable //Repository
{

    public saveEntry(){

        //Save to the db

    }
}


dbAudit:EFContextProvider<BaseDBContext>
{


protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) {
//NEVER HITS THIS BUT DATA GETS SAVED TO DB
 //Do stuff
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inherit from the Breeze EFContextProvider and use that in call to save the entity?

```
public class YourAwesomeProvider : EFContextProvider<YourEFContext>
{
        protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
        {
                // create audit record and add to your instance of your context
                // this.Context.YourAuditEntity.Add(...)
                return base.BeforeSaveEntity(entityInfo);
        }

}
```

Comment: You should also be able to override the Save in your EF context. I'm not quite sure why you are saying that you can't. The EFContextProvider 'extends' the functionality that you provide it via your data context.